# Counting Children in a firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, database-trigger

i'm learing to use firebase and i need some help.
I need to take the number of children of a specific node in a Firebase Function but i can't.

This is my node:

[image: This is my node]

I would like to write a trigger that after a new user is created in `watingRoom`, checking the total number of users in waitingRoom and returns different things based on this number.

This is my code:

```js
exports.createOtherNode = functions.database
.ref('/waitingRoom/{userID}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

    const usersInWatingRoom = snapshot.ref.parent.once('value', (datasnapshot) => {
        const numberOfChildren = datasnapshot.numChildren()
        return numberOfChildren
    });
    console.log(usersInWatingRoom)

    if(usersInWatingRoom > 100)
      //RETURN SOMETHING
    else
      //RETURN SOMETHING ELSE    

 });
```

The code work but instead of a number, usersInWatingRoom return like a promise.

```
(console log: Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
)
```

I expected value 2, so that I can work on the `if`.

how can fix that? do you advise me another way to take the number of children of a node in a `onCreate` trigger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An understanding of javascript promises is [essential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) to making sure that cloud functions work properly for you.

In this case, you need to chain off the returned promise to do the additional work.

You also want to make sure you use the promise form of `once` to ensure you get deterministic results.  The callback form is going to not work well in the cloud function environment as the function can terminate before the callback is made.

Note that returning a value from a backend function (other than returning a promise) doesn't make a lot of sense -- since no caller will get the result (of course, doing something, like a further database update, does make sense).

In any case, here's roughly what you need to do:

```js
exports.createOtherNode = functions.database
  .ref('/waitingRoom/{userID}')
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

    return snapshot.ref.parent.once('value').then((datasnapshot) => {
        const numberOfChildren = datasnapshot.numChildren()
        return numberOfChildren
    }).then((usersInWaitingRoom) => {
        console.log(usersInWaitingRoom)    
        if(usersInWaitingRoom > 100)
          // Do Something
        else
          // Do Something Else
    }); 
 });
```

Comment: Okei, thank you so much! But so, is there a way to get the value of numberOfChildren without having to use the callback form?

Comment: This is promise form, not callback form :)  And no, not if you want the _parent_ child count, since you need to make another call to the database to get that.  If you want the count on the `/waitingRoom/{userID}` node that triggered the function, that exists in the snapshot you get with the function call.